# Fill a div with an image respecting aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to *fill* a div with an image such that at least one image dimension is 100% and the other dimension is either wider or equal size as the div, whilst respecting the image's aspect ratio.

An example could use the classes `wide` and `tall` like this:

```html
<div class="tall">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Klaproos.jpg/266px-Klaproos.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="wide">
  <img src="https://groenevrijdag.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/klaproos2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.tall img { width: 100%;  margin-top: -50%; }
div.wide img { height: 100%; margin-left: -50%; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7tuod6vu/

I'm looking for a pure HTML+CSS solution which works for responsive rectangular (not necessarily square) divs. For this particular reason, Javascript would be a pain as one would need to determine whether the width or height should be 100% on every resize. Server side wouldn't even be an option.

Does a pure HTML+CSS solution exist for this?

**EDIT** Should have been clear about this from the beginning, sorry about that :( I'm not looking for the background-image solution, since it does not allow base64-inhtml representation of images. Moreover, I think background-image's are semantically different from `<img>`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the CSS **`object-fit`** property.

> [**5.5. Sizing Objects: the `object-fit`
>   property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#the-object-fit)
>
> The `object-fit` property specifies how the contents of a replaced
>   element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and
>   width.
>
> *Here are two of the values:*
>
> - **`cover`**
>
>   The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>     filling the element's entire content box.
> - **`contain`**
>
>   The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>     fitting within the element's content box.

So, with `cover` the image retains its aspect ratio and covers all available space. Of course, this means that much of an image may be cropped off-screen.

With `contain` the aspect ratio is also maintained, but the image scales to fit within the box. This means that an image may have whitespace on the left and right, or top and bottom.

---

*Browser Compatibility*

As of this writing, [`object-fit` is not supported by Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit). For a workaround see:

- [Neat trick for CSS `object-fit` fallback on Edge (and other browsers)](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3)
- [fitie - An `object-fit` polyfill for Internet Explorer](https://github.com/jonathantneal/fitie)
- [object-fit-images -  Adds support for `object-fit` on IE9, IE10, IE11, Edge and other old browsers](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/)
- [Polyfill (mostly IE) for CSS `object-fit` property to fill-in/fit-in images into containers.](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit)

---

*More information*

- [MDN `object-fit` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- [CSS-Tricks `object-fit` property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)
- [`object-fit` browser support @ caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution without using background images and with HTML and CSS only: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGGObQ

(change `overflow` to `visible` in the `.container1` rule to see the full pictures. The numbers in them are their original size in pixels.)

It uses `position: absolute` on the images, and depending on the format (two classes, as suggested by yourself) a `top` *or* `left` of `50%` that moves the position reference into the (horizontal or vertical) center, and a `transform : translate` setting that moves the position reference point of the image back from that center by `50%` of their own size, which results in centering:

```css
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img.landscape {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  left: 50%;
}
img.portrait {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x500/09d/fff" class="landscape">
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x900/0d9/fff" class="portrait">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact solution, but it could be an implementation that you could try to make your code work. Here is an example:

As you can't predict the aspect ratio of the image here is what I would do:

**HTML:**
Set the div tag to 'fill':

```
<div class="fill"></div>
```

**CSS:**
This will place your image as the background, and stretch it to fit the div size without distortion.

```
.fill {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image:"path/to/image.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this, I want an `img` to be inside the div, not a background setting. A particular reason would be if the image is defined by a base64 src, instead of an URI.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the images as the div's backgrounds instead and use `backkground-size:cover`

https://jsfiddle.net/3x5x0v24/

Comment: I don't think backgrounds should be used for images, as they are something else. Thanks though!