# CSS Image expanding over parent div size

Tags: html, css

The title says most of it.
My html:

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="s-inner">
  <figure>
   <img>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
 max-width:500px;
 max-height:200px;
 background:red;
 }
.s-inner{
position: relative;
margin: inherit;
padding:inherit;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
box-sizing:inherit;
margin:auto;
}
/*            Inside             */
.s-inner > figure{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  .s-inner > figure > img{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

If you inspect the .wrap div you will notice that the image is popping out and being larger than the div,how that be fixed for image to scale the .wrap div size.[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uvpt3ta/3/)

Comment: So? That's the default behaviour. If you don't want that you can "hide" by adding `overflow; hidden` to parent or you can make the image have a percentage height.

Comment: Consider the CSS **`object-fit`** property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34301817/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B i do not want to use it as it is not supported by IE and Edge

Comment: IE workarounds for `object-fit`: [**HERE**](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3) and [**HERE**](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when the image you have is bigger than the division .. image cannot fit in it. so you have to set width and height for the image also

```
  .s-inner > figure > img {
     height: 196px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
     width: 500px;
       }
```

or the responsive way

```
 .s-inner > figure > img {
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `div.wrap` element's width and height are set to `500px` and `200px` respectively. The aspect ratio of this width and height is `5:2`. Your image, on the other hand, has the resolution `2048x1376` which translates to `64:43` in aspect ratio. If we scale it down, we get `5:3.35`.

When you compare the two aspect ratios, `5:2` and `5:3.35`, you see that the image is taller than the `div.wrap` element.

I can think of three different ways to approach this

First, you can stretch the image to fit in: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uvpt3ta/4/)

```
.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.wrap * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Second, fit the image in keeping the aspect ratio: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uvpt3ta/5/)

```
.s-inner > figure > img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 200px; // add height of the .wrap
}
```

And three, you hide the overflowing part of the image and reposition the image: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uvpt3ta/6/)

```
.wrap {
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden; // hide overflow
}
.s-inner > figure > img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: calc(-335.938px + 200px); // reposition the image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add `overflow: hidden` to your `wrap` div and `width: 100%;` to sub divs.

css:

```
.wrap{
  max-width:500px;
  max-height:200px;
  background:red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.s-inner{
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:inherit;
    margin:auto;
  }
/*            Inside             */
    .s-inner > figure{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
      .s-inner > figure > img{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3uvpt3ta/7/

Answer (score 0):

This demo shows that the `.warp` element isn't overflowed by the "image", *but* it is expanded by the "image". The major changes are:

- Added defaults styles
- `.wrap` is [`display: table`](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)
- `.s-inner` is [`display: table-cell`](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)
- `.s-inner` removed `flex` properties
- The `<img>` is removed.
- The image `src` is now assigned to `figure` [`background-image`](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)
- [`background-size: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images) is added to `figure` as well. This is similar to [`object: fit`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/). With the value of `contain`, the image will not be clipped nor will it not get distorted on resizing. In fact it tries to maintain it's original ratio.
- `figure` is [`100vw x 100vh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593342/2813224), basically if not contained, it will expand from one edge of the screen to the other edge both horizontally and vertically.
- Added a title and icon because it looks nice.
- Try resizing it, it's responsive but the core elements (the ones inside the `<body>`) don't entirely rely on percentage lengths. The trick is to have a width and height that's explicitly set to an [absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) and/or [intrinsic](http://alistapart.com/d/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/example2.html) measurements. Then work your way down the layers alternating between relative and absolute.
- It's also good to start off with a [`display`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) as a foundation, it can be a classic `block` and `inline-block`, or `flex`, or my favorite `table`. If consistent to the type of `display` you decide to use, the less confusing it'll be.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/f0jmv9hz/)

**Snippet**

```css
/* Defaults ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 16px/1.428 'Raleway';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
/* Modified OP ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

.wrap {
  display: table;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
.s-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}
.s-inner > figure {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://www.trbimg.com/img-4fad2af0/turbine/hc-american-school-for-the-deaf-20120510-006);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
figure:before {
  content: '';
  font-size: 3em;
}
.title {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px 30px 0 35%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600' rel='stylesheet'/>

<main class="wrap">
  <section class="s-inner">
    <figure>
      <figcaption class="title">
        <h1>
   HC American School for the Deaf
    </h1>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</main>
```