# Using classes in HTML doesn't work with css, but regular datatypes do

Tags: html, css

So, here is my problem. I'm making a website, and my HTML file just refuses to work with classes. Here is my html code and CSS :

```css
.card {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="img/paarthurnax.jpg" alt="Sorry, we have troubles with connection">
</div>
```

Image does not line up properly when class is used. Interestingly, if i substitute ".card" with simply "div", it works.

But it refuses to work with classes. I also tried doing it with different datatypes, like paragraph, title and lists, and classes still don't work. I tried looking into possible "grammar" mistakes, but in tutorial video i watched, it used same code, letter-to-letter and it worked. Brackets' latest version was used to write code, if it can help.

Comment: Can you show your desired output on this one? It's difficult to tell why your CSS doesn't work when using classes but DIV as a selector works on your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Image expanding over parent div size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703139/css-image-expanding-over-parent-div-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
.card {
    width : 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

possible solution:

```
.card {
    width : 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card img{
    width : 100%;
    height : auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, it worked! Why did this happen, is it a logic error or compilator not knowing path to image?

Comment: the thing is, the `img` width is disrespecting the `div`, so we set it to 100% to follow the same width of `div` as 400px;

Comment: Anyway, i'm glad it helps

Comment: Tbh, now i wonder, why that guy in tutorial video didn't have this problem. Do you know why?