# Making img respect height of flex container

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a wrapper `div` of, say, 100px height (the height could be any value).
Inside that `div` I have 2 more `div`s. The first one takes as much height as the content inside it takes, while the second one takes the remaining height.

The second `div` contains an image (random width/height, could be bigger than the available height/width). Is there a way to make the image **NOT** force it's height/width on the container `div`? (And also preserve the image's ratio)

Demo: http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/JXLxwL The red bordered box shouldn't overflow the black bordered box.

Please refrain if your answer contains hardcoded values or javascript.

Really, **please refrain** if your answer contains hardcoded values or javascript.

Comment: Be aware that the `flex` rules you have applied in `.flex-prop-0` and `flex-prop-1` are doing nothing. The `flex` property applies only to flex items. Since you haven't applied `display: flex` to the parent container (`.wrapper`), they are being ignored.

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you for noticing. I updated my code. Actually, the result is the same, so I don't think that makes any difference, but anyways, I updated the code.

Comment: It made a difference in testing the flex property. Once it's in a flex container, adjusting the flex rule in `flex-prop-1` to `flex: 1 1 auto`, gets the borders to snap into place. Then next step would be fixing the aspect ratio (which is the real tricky part). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMmryQ

Comment: Indeed! A simple `object-fit` should make it work. Edit: Yes, it did: http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/mPxodY

Comment: I love the `object-fit` property. The only reason I don't recommend it yet is incomplete browser support. It's not supported by IE.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: However, there are possible IE workarounds. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34301817/3597276