# How can I stretch/shrink any size image to best fit a square, with only CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I have a perfectly square DIV - 500 x 500px.

I am going to be displaying images of unknown size in that DIV... some of the images are horizontal and some are vertical; some are larger than 500px tall or wide, some are smaller than 500px tall or wide. I don't control the image size.

How can I have any image I place in the DIV be expanded or reduced to best fill the box? My goal is that one axis of the image is always 500px, and the other axis is resized to fit. (This means that if the image is not perfectly square, there will always be blank space on either side of the image for vertical images, or above and below the image for horizontal images. That's ok.)

I know I can use JS or something server-side to do some math on the image sizes and compute new dimensions on the fly that way, but I'm seeking a CSS-only solution. Can flexboxes accomplish this?

Comment: you can't do anything if you set size (width,height,max width,max height) your images will expand. not look good.
if your users upload images your can let them to crop images.(set size of crop Square 500*500px).
so they can handle it and make it right.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34301340/3597276

Comment: Checking up on older answer and found this one. My I ask you to accept/upvote the most useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [CSS object-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#the-object-fit) property is still note widely supported, and you have a fixed container, why not use `background-image:...`/`background-size:contain`

```css
.image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid red;                  /* to mark each box in this sample */
}

.nr1 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/600/animals/1);
}
.nr2 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/animals/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="image nr1">
</div>

<div class="image nr2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: See Result at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyBXKZ

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http//images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Lenovo-p780-camera-sample-10.jpg" alt="Sample image">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.image-container {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500px;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `background-image` property makes the loading rely on CSS, which has some drawbacks, such as performance. Because of that, I came up with the following solution:

```
<div
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }}
>
  <img
    style={{
      minWidth: "100%",
      minHeight: "100%",
      objectFit: "cover",
    }}
    alt=""
    src={url}
  />
</div>
```

The above will scale up an image in order for it to **cover** the parent container.
If you just need to fit inside, then change `objectFit` to `contain`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). For object-fit to work you have to set a size to your image, since I want it to cover the whole box I simply set `width: 100%`

```css
.image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;                  /* to mark each box in this sample */
}

.image img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600" alt="">
</div>

<div class="image">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x400" alt="">
</div>
```