# Image takes all the space in flexbox div (100%) without deforming the div

Tags: css, flexbox

Image takes all the space in flexbox div (100%) without deforming the div. So not the div adjusts to contain an image, but image adjusts to fullfill a div.

I know that in flexbox inner div that contain an image will adjust to size of teh image if you say:

```
img {height : 100%; width : 100%;}
```

I need an image in flex div to take all the space of the div. So 100% height and 100% width without affecting the div itself. So whatever is the size of a div I need an image in it to strech and occupy all the avalable space without changing the div itself. How do I do it?

note: if it is not possible with flexbox - then how can I achieve the result using different technic?

Here is the html:

```
<div class='box-wrap'>
   <div class='box'>
      <div>
         <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css :

```
.row {
   margin-top      : 10px;
   display         : flex;
   flex-direction  : row;
   flex-wrap       : wrap;
   border          : 1px solid silver;
}
.box,.box-wrap {
   background      : white;
   flex            : 1 1 8%;
   border          : 1px solid #aaa;
   margin          : 10px;
   justify-content : space-between;
   letter-spacing  : 1px;
   box-sizing      : border-box;
} 
.box-wrap {
   padding         : 0.5em 10px;
   background      : white;
}
```

Here is the corresponding codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwYeJX

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me. But maybe you can use the CSS `object-fit` property: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34301817/3597276

Comment: it doesnt work..i just want to maybe break the primal sie of an img but dill all the div and dont touch its size

Comment: Can you provide a live demo?

Comment: Try to reword your question, stating explicitly the current behavior and the expected behavior. Try also to make your example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `object-fit` property for the img :

```
.box img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make the img fill the entire height of its container, you can set its container to flex (this then makes the image stop keeping its aspect ration fixed).
Then set the width and height of the container to whichever values you desire:

```
.box div {
display:flex;
height:600px;
width:100%;
}
```

And to fill out its full width do this:

```
.box div img {
width:100%;
}
```

In this particular case, it resizes the width according to the window and has a fixed height: https://jsfiddle.net/ (demo here)

COMMENT: Also unless there's a very specific reason you need all those nested divs, you could easily remove the innermost (3rd level) div and apply these values to the 2nd level div.